# Showing properties of Cantor space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we have the proposition that

Any subset of the real line that is compact, totally disconnected and perfect is homeomorphic to the Cantor Set.

And consider the Cantor space $2^{\omega}= \prod_{i=1}^{\omega} \{0,1\}_i$, and we know that it is also compact, totally disconnected and perfect, how would we use the proposition to show that it is also homeomorphic to the Cantor set as well?

Comment: In the case of $2^\omega$ you can show directly that the two spaces are homeomorphic.

Comment: If you want to use the proposition, you must show that $2^{\omega}$ is a subset of the real line.

Comment: But how would an element like 010101... be a subset of the real line?

Comment: You would need to embed the space as a subset of the real line, @lim. And to do this you may as well embed it in such a way that its image is the Cantor set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^{\omega}$ is homeomorphic to the classical ternary Cantor set C via the map $x \mapsto \sum x(n)/3^n$.